# Java: create custom exception class package.Exception

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to reuse Java's reserved name "Exception" to define your own class with the same name "Exception" but in the package?

Below obviously wouldn't compile:

```
package mypackage;
public class Exception extends Exception { ...
```

Comment: If it wouldn't compile, haven't you essentially answered your own question at this point?

Comment: @MetroidFan2002 isn't there a chance that some trick exists that I may not know?

Comment: as the answer below, for example... :)

Comment: Don't do that. Use a more specific name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but you have to fully-qualify the original though:

```
class Exception extends java.lang.Exception
```

It's not a very good idea to reuse names of basic classes like that though.

Comment: excellent! thank you. would you mind commenting why isn't it a good idea?

Comment: It's not a good idea because virtually every other programmer would think that Exception means java.lang.Exception and would get confused why their code won't compile since they didn't import your specific exception type.  Plus the name gives you no context on why you'd throw this Exception subtype.

Comment: @OlegShirokikh Other people reading your code will expect `Exception` to mean something else. Also it's annoying to have to write `java.lang.Exception` all over the place.

Comment: Paul - makes perfect sense. Thanks for answering the original question and also commenting on applicability!

Comment: @OlegShirokikh Glad I could help.